# Problems opening vector layers after shifting the location of the saved layer

Tags: qgis, layers

At work, we have recently changed from MapInfo to QGIS and our operating system from Windows to Ubuntu. We run 4 computers each with its own copy of QGIS, all connected to a server. The following are some of our problems:
1.  We cannot save straight from QGIS to the server. From our reading, we expect that this is caused by having separate copies of QGIS and that if we had one copy of QGIS on the server, we could save directly to the server.

Is this true please?

2. Although tedious, this problem is easy enough to circumvent: Save to the desktop and then shift it to the server.
3. However, after creating a new vector layer, I’ll save all the associated files and project and then carefully shift all the files to the server. Returning to the same project later one of three things happen with no consistency!!??

(i) the vector layer will opens perfectly.
(ii)    the layer ‘opens’ but the attribute table is empty and thus nothing exists in the layer. 
(iii)   the vector layer will open but we are unable to edit it. 
Any ideas please?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? What's the server OS? Can other applications save read/write to server? (I'm writing QGIS projects from Ubuntu notebook to Win server without issues.) Which data file or database formats are you using?

Comment: We are using QGIS 2.18.2 with the server running LINUX RAID 1.

The server connection is SSH.

Comment: @underdark. Additions to my reply above: We cannot attach anything from the server to an email directly. WE have to save it to the desktop or into Documents first. Similarly when saving an email attachment. This is all security as we got badly hacked several months ago. We can open projects on the server., but what the shape files do on "opening" seems to be in the lap of the gods. It is shape files that are giving us the trouble. I do not understand your question about "data file or database format".

Comment: Without understanding your security measures, I doubt we'll be able to help much.